# Can we map $\Bbb{Z}[G]$ back to $G^{\text{ab}}$ using a group homomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, group-homomorphism, quotient-group

Let $G$ be a finite group and $\Bbb{Z}[G]$ be the group ring.

Define $f : \Bbb{Z}[G] \to G^{\text{ab}}$ by $f(\sum\limits_{g \in G} x_g g) = \prod\limits_{g \in G} \tilde{g}^{x_g}$.  Then $f$ is a group homomorphism, where $\tilde{g}$ is the coset of $g$ in $G$'s abelianization.  Let's check:

$$
f( x + y) = \prod_{g \in G} \tilde{g}^{x_g + y_g} = \prod_{g \in G} \tilde{g}^{x_g} \prod_{g \in G} \tilde{g}^{y_g}
$$
by the Abelian property of $G^{\text{ab}}$.

But is this map well-defined i.e. since the abelianization of a group is a quotient and all?

I think so since if $x = \sum_{g \in G} x_g g = \sum_{g \in G} y_g g= y$ then $f(x) = \prod_{g \in G} \tilde{g}^{x_g} = f(y)$.  I think, but I'm not 100% sure yet.

If yes or no, I would also like to know if you can come up with some other homomorphisms $\Bbb{Z}[G] \to G$ or $G^{\text{ab}}$.

---

Okay, so apparently it is indeed a group hom.  But I want now to compute its kernel.  I think it might have something to do with the norm element of the group ring, $N_G = \sum_{g \in G} g$.

Comment: In the definition of $f$, why $g\in G^{ab}$? I think this should be $g\in G$, since we are in the domain $\mathbb{Z}[G]$.

Comment: @withoutfeather thank you! Fixed it.

Comment: Give. any groups $G,H$ and a homomorphism $h:G\to H$ there is a related ring homomorphism $h’:\mathbb Z[G]\to \mathbb Z[H].$  in particular, $h’$ is a homomorphism of the additive groups. This then reduces to the question, if $A$ is abelian then your $f$ is a group homomorphism $\mathbb Z[A]\to A.$

Comment: The kernel of your map is big and depends on the structure of the group (essentially the kernel will contain all the relations between the elements). For each $g \in G$, the element $z_g = g+g^{-1} \in \mathbb{Z}[G]$ is in the kernel (and in the special case of $g=1_G$, you can take $z_{1_G} =1_G  \in \mathbb{Z}[G]$). But they don't generate everything, for example in $G = \mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$, the element $x = \overline{1} + \overline{2} + \overline{3}$ is also in the kernel.

Comment: @JoelCohen I think, but not sure yet that if we call a subset of $G \supset X$ self inverting when elementwise $X = X^{-1}$, then $\ker f = \{ x \in \Bbb{Z}[G] \ | \ \text{support}(x) = \{ g \in G : x_g \neq 0 \}$ is self-inverting $\}$.  Maybe, but by your last example, that's not true, so hmm...  Certainly these self-inverting set sums are a subset of the kernel.  I'm working with the product of squares though, so it might be true for that where as $2 + 4 + 6 = 12 \pmod 6$ and is self-inverting (ie. you double or "square" your $1 + 2 + 3$ example).

Comment: $N_G$ is not necessarily in the kernel of your map. Consider $G = \mathbb{Z}_2$.

Comment: @CharlieCunningham product of squares ie.  So $2\cdot 2 + 2\cdot1 = 6 = 0 \pmod 2$

Comment: Let $G$ be a finite group.

$$
\Bbb{Z}[G] \xrightarrow{\pi} G^{\text{ab}}, \\
\pi(\sum_{g \in G} x_g g) = \prod_{g \in G} \tilde{g}^{2x_g},
$$
is a group hom, where $\tilde{g} = $ the coset of $g$ in $G$'s abelianization, $G^{\text{ab}}$.  $\ker \pi = \{ x \in \Bbb{Z}[G] \ | \ \prod \tilde{g}^{2x_g} = \tilde{1}\}$, but,

$$
\tilde{g}_1^{2 x_1} \cdots \tilde{g}_n^{2 x_n} = \tilde{1} \iff \\
\prod_{i = 1..|G|} \tilde{g_i}^{x_i} = \text{ its inverse}
$$
So does $\ker \pi = \{ x \in \Bbb{Z}[G] \ | \ \text{support}(x) = \{ g : x_g \neq 0\}$ is a self-inverse subset of $G \}$?

Comment: @CharlieCunningham see my edit in the comments.  It would be cool if it had this simple description (the kernel did).

Comment: I think if you keep changing the question you should make a new post.

Comment: @ShineOnYouCrazyDiamond : The kernel is bigger than what you describe (note that the subset you describe is actually generated by the elements $(z_g)_{g \in G}$). Basically the kernel will contain all the relations inside the group, which is highly depend on the structure of the specific group you pick. Another example : take $g \in G$ and denote $n_g \in \mathbb{N}^*$ its order. From the relation $g^{n_g} = 1_G$, we get that $x_g = n_g . g \in \mathbb{Z}[G]$ is in the kernel. If you want another family of examples, take $a, b \in G$ and denote $c = ab$, then $a+b-c$ is in the kernel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the composition $\gamma:\mathbb{Z}[G]\to\mathbb{Z}[G^{\mathrm{ab}}]\to G^{\mathrm{ab}}$. Note $G^{\mathrm{ab}}=G/G'$ where $G'=[G,G]$.

The ring homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}[G]\to\mathbb{Z}[G/N]$ (where $N\trianglelefteq G$) has kernel $K=\bigoplus_{G/N} gI_N$, where

$$ I_N = \left\{\sum_{n\in N} a_n x_n\mid \sum_{n\in N} a_n=0\right\}=\bigoplus_{n\in N}\mathbb{Z}\cdot(n-e) $$

is the augmentation ideal (the kernel of the coefficient-summing map $\mathbb{Z}[N]\to\mathbb{Z}$).

And $\mathbb{Z}[G^{\mathrm{ab}}]$ (under addition) is the free abelian group on $G^{\mathrm{ab}}$'s underlying set, so we expect the kernel of the multiply-together map $m:\mathbb{Z}[G^{\mathrm{ab}}]\to G^{\mathrm{ab}}$ to be generated by $G^{\mathrm{ab}}$'s multiplication table, i.e.

$$ K'=\sum_{x,y\in G^{\mathrm{ab}}} \mathbb{Z}\cdot(x+y-xy). $$

Pulling $K'$ back to $\mathbb{Z}[G]$ yields the kernel of the composition $\gamma$. Pulling a $\mathbb{Z}$-basis for $K'$ back to a set in $\mathbb{Z}[G]$ and taking the union with a $\mathbb{Z}$-basis for $K$ should yield a $\mathbb{Z}$-basis for the kernel of $\gamma$.

Comment: What does 'pulling back' mean in this context?

Comment: Taking preimage of $K'$ under the map $\mathbb{Z}[G]\to\mathbb{Z}[G^{\rm ab}]$. Or, in the case of the $\Bbb Z$-basis for $K'$, picking representatives for their fibers.

Answer (score 3):

The additive group of $\mathbb{Z}[G]$ is the free abelian group on the set underlying $G$. Since we have a quotient map $G \to G/[G, G]$, it follows that there is an induced homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}[G] \to G/[G, G]$. Well-definedness is only an issue for maps defined on quotients.

Comment: Can we compute the kernel of that induced hom?

Comment: See my edit about the norm element.  That's what I'm really interested in.  I wanted a hom from the group ring such that the kernel is $(N_G)$ or something similar.  Thanks.